# Connect to remote Openbravo ERP Appliance

Tags: ssh, vmware, openbravo

I have my Openbravo appliance running by VMWare workstation on top of Win7 which is in a LAN connected to internet by router.

When I start the appliance. I can access ERP web console by typing in the address it gave at the end of the process (for example, 192.168.1.107). All computer in the LAN can access this address as well which is fine for now.

However, in the future, I need to access this console from my home pc running Win7 (which is, of course, connected to the internet). How do i set this up?. I have try the method given in http://planet.openbravo.com/?p=8612 (see case 3 -  Expose my local ERP into a remote network)

I tried (in Openbravo Appliance console running in VMWare)

```
ssh -R :9999:localhost:80 myhomepc@101.108.70.128
```

(where 101.108.70.128 is the ip of my home pc read from whatismyip.org)

but it give the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host 101.108.78.128 port 22: connection timed out
```

Do I missed any step required?
What should i do the successfully connect to my Openbravo instance?

Comment: do you have and ssh server installed on your home PC?

Answer (score 1):

Best is to ask those questions directly in the Openbravo ERP forums over there: http://forge.openbravo.com

The case 3 from the blog-post you are referring to makes 2 implicit assumptions.
a.) the remote computer runs an ssh-server
b.) This ssh-server can be connected to from the erp instance

One of the two assumptions seems to not hold in your case either your win7 box does not run an ssh server and/or the router of your home network does not forward port 22 from the outside to your win7 box.
Without further information i assume both items are not done.

Let me propose another solution instead. As you want to connct to the commandline of the erp appliance from home you could do the following:
Configure the router of the network with the erp appliance to connect some external port (i.e. 2222) to the ip of the appliance, destination port 22.

This will allow you to access it from the home network (or any other system from the internet knowing the ip/port).
Using an external port different from 22 some simple ssh brute-force passwords scans.
As the appliance by default does not allow login by password but only allows authentication by public-key this is secure to not allow unauthorized access to your system.

After this either use case 1 from the blog-post or an normal ssh tunnel like (ssh -p external-port user@externalipoferplan -L 9999:localhost:22' and then access the ERP via 'http://localhost' from your win7 box.

If that is too complicated and you want to just make the ERP webinterface available from the internet without having the extra ssh security in the middle then you can just configure the router of the erp lan instead to forward port 80 or 443 (http or https) to the erp-instance and access the system directly from anymore as if it would be on some public server in the internet.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but this still comes, up while searching so had to correct. I don't think http://forge.openbravo.com/ is the right place, infact I wasn't able to find any working link to ask questions on their own site.